# Interactive Web Mapping for a Non Programmer?

Tags: arcmap, web-mapping, html, svg

I'm looking to map something similar to this:

http://tipstrategies.com/geography-of-jobs/

Does anyone know, first off, how this was put together?
From what I've researched so far, it seems this type of interactive, mouse-over web mapping involves SVG (?), HTML (?), or JavaScript (?) (or a combination of all three)? It doesn't seem wise to try to master all three of those before embarking on an interactive web mapping project. What I'd like to do is hone in on exactly what I need to know and do to make something like the above Geography of Jobs.

Anyone have a recommendation for precisely what type of code to learn, resources to help one write that code, etc., for interactive web mapping?

PS, I use ArcMap 10.3 to create my vectors.

PSS, I know very little about coding, but am very very open to learning.